# android : Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have the error as below :

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jsontest, PID: 9486
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.jsontest/com.example.jsontest.ClosetMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
at com.example.jsontest.ClosetMainActivity.<init>(ClosetMainActivity.java:69)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
```

I have checked my manifest file and every activity has been added, but I still get the error. 
I don't know why.Does anyone can help? 
Thanks.

The only method I use when I start the application up is:

```
private void DbCheckUser(){
    GlobalVariable globalVariable = (GlobalVariable)LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
    String UserId = globalVariable.UserId.toString();
    String sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(fbId) AS G FROM member where fbId="+UserId;
    try{

        String result = DBConnector.executeQuery(sqlString,phpUrl);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        Log.e("result",result);
        JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        if (jsonData.getString("G").equals("0")){ 

            String ImgUrl ="http://graph.facebook.com/"+UserId+"/picture?type=large";
            String InsertMemberSqlString = "INSERT INTO member(mId, fbId, fbName, fbEmail, fbIcon, fbIconType)"
                                             +" VALUES ('','"+UserId+"','"+UserName+"','"+UserEmail+"','"+ImgUrl+"','image/png')";
            String insertResult = DBConnector.executeQuery(InsertMemberSqlString, "http://140.117.71.81/connect_to_cloze.php");
            Log.e("insertResult",insertResult);
        }
        else{ 
            String mIdSqlString = "SELECT mId FROM member WHERE fbId='"+UserId+"'";
            try{
                String mIdResult = DBConnector.executeQuery(mIdSqlString, "http://140.117.71.81/connect_to_cloze.php");
                JSONArray jsonArraymId = new JSONArray(mIdResult);
                final JSONObject jsonDatamId = jsonArraymId.getJSONObject(0);

                globalVariable.mId = jsonDatamId.getString("mId");
                //mId = jsonDatamId.getString("mId");
                Log.e("mId",globalVariable.mId);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(LoginActivity.this, ClosetMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); 

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("error",e.toString());

            }               
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("LogInError",e.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: What line is line 69 in ClosetMainActivity.java? Your Exception is being thrown there.

Comment: `ClosetMainActivity.java:69`

Comment: line 69 in ClosetMainActivity.java is 
GlobalVariable globalVariable = (GlobalVariable)ClosetMainActivity.this.getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `globalVariable = (GlobalVariable)ClosetMainActivity.this.getApplicationContext();` after `super.onCreate()`. Do not attempt to use superclass methods in `Activity` prior to `super.onCreate()`, as they may not work. According to your stack trace, you are calling `getApplicationContext()` from a data member initializer for your class, and that is before `super.onCreate()`.